# What is this motherboard component that looks like a bead of solder [photo], and can it be repaired/replaced?

Tags: power, pcb, components, repair

[image]

As you can see, the one on the top is burnt. Whenever I plug the power adapter into the wall, the component releases a puff of smoke and the adapter instantly shuts itself off. The damage to the component was caused by an issue with the DC power jack, seen directly to the right. I replaced the DC jack with a new one (as you might infer by the evidence of my sloppy workmanship) but unfortunately the problem with the indicated component remains.

So, I'm just wondering, what is that thing, what does it do, and can I repair or replace it. I'm hoping that I can just replace the solder and it will work again, but I'm not exactly holding my breath.

Comment: I think it actually *is* a bead of solder, and your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: As @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams pointed out, it appears to be a solder bridge aka solder jumper: A blob of solder used to short two adjacent exposed pads on the PCB. The burn marks indicate that the solder blob is probably heating up due to the current through it. My first approach would be to replace the solder blob with lower resistance silver-based solder: Reduce the resistance of the "jumper", and it will generate less heat when passing current. Or, just use small bits of copper wire for the shunts.

Comment: It seems like it was always there though, so I suspect that something down the line is drawing an abnormally large amount of current and that this is just a symptom.

Comment: @Ignacio What about the fact that the burning was caused by the earlier DC jack issue, does that provide any clues? Also, everything seems to run fine off of the battery. If there is another problem further from the DC jack, I wouldn't know how to find it.

Comment: @Anindo So I could try removing the solder and then soldering on a piece of copper wire to bridge the gap? I don't have ready access to silver solder. Any chance that just replacing the old solder with fresh 63/37 solder would help?

Comment: @MattMunson Yes, I would just go with a copper wire piece for each jumper, not too thin. No, replacing the solder with another blob of similar solder probably isn't going to help much.

Comment: I just want to say for the record that this question should NOT have been voted down as "off topic", so I'm "up" voting it. I've been repairing electronics for over 40 years, and there's still odd cases where like this that are pretty hard to identify both part and purpose. I DO wish the photo was more enlarged. Maybe it is just a "solder blob", but when and why would such a technique be used? In these days where you often can forget about obtaining a schematic without an "authorized repair center" license, it benefits everyone to have such mysteries shown and identified.